# Select pkg_name.function_name

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is this query valid? if the package(with proper definition and body) and function exists and works fine.

```
Select "JK" As Name, 
       pckg_name1.function_name1(number1,number2) 
from dual
```

Comment: What happened when you ran that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function call is fine (assuming the function returns a SQL data type - you cannot use PL/SQL specific data types, e.g. Boolean), but your quoting for **JK** is wrong. You have to use single quotes instead of double ones:

```
Select 'JK' As Name, 
       pckg_name1.function_name1(number1,number2) 
from dual
```